# JDialog goes behind after progressbar finishes

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar, jdialog

I have `JPanel`, from which I am opening a search criteria Dialog that extends `AbstractAIFDialog`. It consists of search criteria text field, result table view and search button. After clicking Search, in this dialog, I need to show progress bar till I get the result from database.

I am calling the below function when Search button is clicked:

```
SearchResult res = SearchExecuteHelperUtils.execute(searchService, 0);
```

The above execute function definition is as below:

```
public static SearchResult execute(SearchProvider searchService, int nLoadAll)
        throws Exception

{    
    final Display display = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay();
    if(display != null)
        display.syncExec(new Runnable() {

            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    (new ProgressMonitorDialog(display.getActiveShell())).run(true, true, executeSearch);
                }
                catch(InvocationTargetException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

The problem is that I have the `JPanel` open. On top of it I have the `Search criteria` dialog. On click of `Search` button, progress bar appears, but after progress bar closes, results are populated in the `Search` dialog but the dialog goes behind the `JPanel`.

What should I do?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).

Answer (score 2):

> ..I have the `JPanel` open. On top of it I have the `Search criteria` dialog. On click of `Search` button, progress bar appears, but after progress bar closes, results are populated in the `Search` dialog but the dialog goes behind the `JPanel`.

It seems as though the `JPanel` should be the component passed to a `JOptionPane` that shows the progress bar/search results.

Comment: Which Panel should be sent?

In the below line of code:

*SearchResult res = SearchExecuteHelperUtils.execute(searchService, 0);*


searchService is the current JDialog that is passed to the execute function and inside execute(), this searchService does not extend from Shell and ProgressMonitor needs a shell; so we get the shell from display.getActiveShell(). 

Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: *"Which Panel should be sent?"*  Where is your SSCCE?  *"Am I wrong somewhere?"*  Spending time speculating rather than making an SSCCE?